# Ajax results not displayed using angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to display a list of events after ajax callback using AngularJS

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="event in events">{{ event.content }}</li>
</ul>
```

CONTROLLER:

```
app.controller("myctrl", function ($scope, mySrv) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $scope.events = mySrv.getEvents(26);

});
```

SERVICE:

```
app.factory('mySrv', function ($http) {
    return {
        getEvents: function (i_RequestID) {

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/GetOptimizationResultEvents',
                data: { RequestID: i_RequestID }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now there are no errors but i see no results..
what am i dooing wrong here ?

Comment: Are you using angular with webAPI?

Comment: you have to return the `$http`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just like @koox00 said, you have to return the $http

```
app.factory('mySrv', function ($http) {
    return {
        getEvents: function (i_RequestID) {

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/GetOptimizationResultEvents',
                data: { RequestID: i_RequestID }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Personally I prefer to transform my raw data in the factory

```
app.factory('mySrv', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
        getEvents: function (i_RequestID) {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/Home/GetOptimizationResultEvents',
                    data: { RequestID: i_RequestID }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    // transforms

                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(function(reason) {
                    reject(reason);
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your `getEvents`-functions needs to return the promise of the call:

```
getEvents: function (i_RequestID) {

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/GetOptimizationResultEvents',
            data: { RequestID: i_RequestID }
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            return response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
    }
```

This will make `getEvents` return a promise, so where you use it you go like this:

```
app.controller("myctrl", function ($scope, mySrv) {
    $scope.message = "";

    mySrv.getEvents(26).then(function(result){
        $scope.events = result;
    });

});
```

you might need to do a `$scope.$apply()` after you assign `$scope.events = result;`

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried returning the promise?

```
app.factory('mySrv', function ($http) {
    return {
        getEvents: function (i_RequestID) {

        return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Home/GetOptimizationResultEvents',
                data: { RequestID: i_RequestID }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
     app.controller("myctrl",['$scope', 'mySrv', function ($scope, mySrv) {
           $scope.message = "";
           $scope.events = mySrv.getEvents(26);

    }]);
```

also check with controller and app script files properly loaded